# Saving entries on tkinter to sqlite3

Tags: python, tkinter, sqlite

thanks in advance for any help!

Ive been looking online for a solution and have struggled to find one. Im trying to save some data from a entry text box on tkinter to a table in SQLite3 but am getting the same error every time no matter what I try. Code below.

please note, I only started to learn coding from youtube videos a few days ago. apologies if this is really simple!

```
**python file code**

from tkinter import *
import sqlite3
import tkinter.messagebox

# connect to database
conn = sqlite3.connect("RMS.db")
c = conn.cursor()



# tkinter window
class Application:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master

        # Creating frames in the master
        self.left = Frame(master, width=200, height=60, bg="grey")
        self.left.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.right = Frame(master, width=0, height=0, bg="grey")
        self.right.pack(side=RIGHT)

        # labels for window
        self.driverlevel = Label(self.left, text="Driver Level:", font="calabri 12 bold", fg="white", bg="grey")
        self.driverlevel.place(x=1, y=2)

        # Entries for left window
        self.driverlevel_ent = Entry(self.left, width=20)
        self.driverlevel_ent.place(x=5, y=27)

        # Save Button
        self.submit = Button(self.left, text="Add", font="calabri 12 bold", fg="white", bg="grey", command=self.addlevel)
        self.submit.place(x=140, y=15)

    def addlevel(self):
        self.val1 = self.driverlevel_ent.get()

        if self.val1 == "":
            tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Warning", "Please Enter a Value")
        else:
            sql = "INSERT INTO 'driverlevel' (Level,) VALUES(?,)"
            c.execute(sql, (self.val1))
            conn.commit()
            tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Success", "Driver Level Added")


# objects
root = Tk()
b = Application(root)
root.geometry("200x60+0+0")
root.resizable(False, False)
root.title("Add Driver Level")

root.mainloop()


**error message when saving**

Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\*****\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/*****/PycharmProjects/******/driverlevel.py", line 41, in addlevel
    c.execute(sql, (self.val1))
sqlite3.OperationalError: near ")": syntax error
```

no idea how to overcome this..

Thanks, Josh

Answer (score 1):

You inserted `,` after `Level, and  ?,` which was suppose to be  this `"INSERT INTO 'driverlevel' (Level) VALUES(?)` then insert the comma `,` at the end of `(self.val1,)` to see it as a tuple because you can insert data into `sqlite3` as tuple

You can also insert the data this way

```
sql = "INSERT INTO driverlevel (Level) VALUES(?,)"
conn = sqlite3.connect("RMS.db")
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("INSERT INTO driverlevel(level)VALUES(?)", (self.val1,))
conn.commit()
tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Success", "Driver Level Added")
```

Make sure you closed the db after insertion.

**Full code**

```
from tkinter import *
import sqlite3
import tkinter.messagebox

# connect to database
conn = sqlite3.connect("RMS.db")
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS driverlevel(level text, age text)")
conn.commit()
conn.close()



# tkinter window
class Application:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master

        # Creating frames in the master
        self.left = Frame(master, width=200, height=60, bg="grey")
        self.left.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.right = Frame(master, width=0, height=0, bg="grey")
        self.right.pack(side=RIGHT)

        # labels for window
        self.driverlevel = Label(self.left, text="Driver Level:", font="calabri 12 bold", fg="white", bg="grey")
        self.driverlevel.place(x=1, y=2)

        # Entries for left window
        self.driverlevel_ent = Entry(self.left, width=20)
        self.driverlevel_ent.place(x=5, y=27)

        # Save Button
        self.submit = Button(self.left, text="Add", font="calabri 12 bold", fg="white", bg="grey", command=self.addlevel)
        self.submit.place(x=140, y=15)

    def addlevel(self):
        self.val1 = self.driverlevel_ent.get()

        if self.val1 == "":
            tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Warning", "Please Enter a Value")
        else:
            #sql = "INSERT INTO driverlevel (Level) VALUES(?,)"
          #  conn = sqlite3.connect("RMS.db")
          #  c = conn.cursor()
          #  c.execute("INSERT INTO driverlevel(level)VALUES(?)", (self.val1,))
           # conn.commit()
           # tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Success", "Driver Level Added")

            conn = sqlite3.connect("RMS.db")
            c = conn.cursor()
            sql = "INSERT INTO 'driverlevel' (Level) VALUES(?)"
            c.execute(sql, (self.val1,))
            conn.commit()
            conn.close()

            tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Success", "Driver Level Added")


# objects
root = Tk()
b = Application(root)
root.geometry("200x60+0+0")
root.resizable(False, False)
root.title("Add Driver Level")

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: @JJPS if this solve the problem make sure tick mark sign as i reference for future coders.